# container should automatically adjust to the height of the background image for responsive design css only

Tags: javascript, css, image, responsive-design, background

I working on a responsive design.
If i load the image with the image tag i have no problem with the size, but then it will load on screen too even if i set display:none. This cause loading problems on smartphone devices...
This way i trying to scale it with background-size:contain, but the problem is i have to add an height for the container.
That means if i have a device with different width the image doesn´t fit more.
The same problem with background-size:cover. The image flow over if i change width.  
Would do it just with css, because there are many pictures and this cause loading problems with javascript.

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    background-image:url(../images/backgrounds/Header_phone2.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

**Edit**

My solution with JS in the answer, improvement tipps are welcome

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: The height of the container should automatically adjust to the height of the background image. I changed the question title now. Sry for my bad english. I hope is more clear now.

Comment: You can't do that without javascript.

Comment: :(, there is now possability ? How then other scale there images for smartphones with many and different pictures for each device setting?

Comment: You have to research when and how to only load images when required. It's a complex subject.

Comment: Can you link me a solution for load images only when required ? I searched for that before i wrote the question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made now something, what is working nice for me.
I´m not really good with jquery, this way i´m looking forward for improvement tipps.
Html:
container in container ...
Css stay almost same:

```
#header {
    height:auto;
}
#header-image{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 155px;
     background-image:url(../bilder/backgrounds/Header_phone2.jpg);
     background-size:cover;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
```

Jquery:

```
if ($( window ).width() <= 966) {
  var screenwidth = $(window).width();
    var heightimage = (screenwidth /940) * 198;
    $("#header-image").css("height", heightimage);
}

  $(window).resize(function() {
  if ($( window ).width() <= 966) {
      var screenwidth = $(window).width();
      var heightimage = (screenwidth /940) * 198;
      $("#header-image").css("height", heightimage);
    }
  });
```

This is working fantastic !! Same like you add the image with img tag and the image doesn´t load with screen design. ([look there](https://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/))
If javascript disabled set min-heigth, like this the image is displayed too.
With jquery i calculate the height of the image. For this i take the width from the display, divide it trough image width and multiply it with height from image. => the correct height for the container.
With the windows-resize function you can change the size of the window and it still works. 

This is very simple and works nice for me.
[Click for Jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/hf3dnvz3/5/)

If you use the js script where you delete the src path from img tag, then it will send a request too. With this variant you don´t have problems, look out first link.
Some skilled guys could improve this: select the image width and height with jquery and make a function.